# Proof Involving Irrational and Rational Numbers

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that if $xy$ is irrational then at least one of $x$ and $y$ is irrational.

Here's what I did: 
Let $$r=xy$$ Assume $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $y\in\mathbb{I}$. Assume $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. 
Then $$\frac{r}{x}=y$$ which results in $\frac{r}{x}\in\mathbb{Q}$
However, this is a contradiction to what we assumed. Therefore, $xy$ must be irrational with at least one of $x$ and $y$ irrational.

Is this proof sound/correct? If not, what can I do to improve? I feel as if I'm missing something but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You've proved something different than what was asked: you showed that if exactly one of $x, y$ is irrational (and $x$ is nonzero), then $xy$ is irrational. You were asked to show that if $xy$ is irrational, then at least one of $x, y$ is irrational. To show this, it is maybe easier to show the contrapositive, which says that if $x$ and $y$ are both rational, then $xy$ is rational.

Comment: Your logic is off.  Your argument correctly shows that the product of a rational and an irrational is irrational (well, you should make an exception for the case $r=0=x$ ).  This, however, is not what was asked.  You have to show that if $x,y$ are both rational then the product can not be irrational (note:  this is not difficult).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your proof could use some work.

> Assume $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $y\in\mathbb I$

You are assuming what you are trying to prove! You cannot do this. It seems like maybe you are trying to show that if exactly one of $x$ and $y$ is irrational, then so is their product. This is not what was asked. I would go for a proof by contrapositive: show that if $x$ and $y$ are both rational, then so is their product, which has as its converapositive the statement you need to prove: if $xy$ is irrational, then $x$ and $y$ are not both rational.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume that $x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{I}$, because that is not given in the conditions.

You can show this statement using contrapositives. That is, if both $x,y$ are rational, then so is $xy$.

Comment: I endorse this answer (as if that means anything!) for being classy enough to suggest the contrapositive, rather than contradiction.